# Azure Java SDK: container with multiple volumes

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

I need to mount 2 separate directories as volumes to a newly creted container.
So far I've found the way to mount only one volume since there's no way to add a file share volume via `withNewAzureFileShareVolume` more than once.

Here's my code:

```
ContainerGroup containerGroup = azure.containerGroups()
                .define(containerName)
                .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
                .withExistingResourceGroup("myResourceGroup")
                .withLinux()
                .withPrivateImageRegistry("registry")
                .withNewAzureFileShareVolume("aci-share", shareName)
                .defineContainerInstance(containerName)
                .withImage("image")
                .withVolumeMountSetting("aci-share", "/usr/local/dir1/")
                .withVolumeMountSetting("aci-share-2", "/usr/local/dir2/")
                .attach()
                .withDnsPrefix(team)
                .create();
```

A new storage account gets created with a single file share and I get the following error:
`Volumes 'aci-share-2' in container 'team44783530d' are not found`

Comment: According to the situation, I think you can try to use Azure ARM template to implement it. For more details, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files#mount-multiple-volumes

Comment: Here's the answer from MS Support on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51457